# Initializing arrays with unknown size in HLSL

Tags: c, arrays, memory, initialization, hlsl

I have a small fragment shader that operates on a number of values in an array, however the size of the array is stored in a constant.

The array is declared as follows:

```
float4 colors[(blurRadius*2+1)*(blurRadius*2+1)];
```

and then I proceed to assign them values using a for loop

```
for(int i = -blurRadius; i<= blurRadius; i++)
{
    for(int j = -blurRadius; j<=blurRadius;j++)
    {
        colors[j + blurRadius + ((i+blurRadius)*blurRadius)]=float4(0,0,0,0);
    }
}
```

however, when run the code comes back with the following compiler error:

```
error X4000: variable 'colors' used without having been completely initialized
```

How do I completely initialize an array whose size I don't know in HLSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I'm a bit of an idiot today. The method listed above works perfectly fine, as long as your stride is correct.

Turns out:

```
j + blurRadius + ((i+blurRadius)*blurRadius)
```

Doesn't address the whole array, so some of it was later being accessed when I'd yet to assign a value.